# Node.js Express slowing down after 5 requests

Tags: node.js, express

I've come across a strange issue in my app (Node.js/jQuery/Mongo/Express setup) where connections are slowing down after 5 attempts.

I have a page that has 10 items on, all when clicked proceed to open a lightbox, with then in turn grabs data from the database. If I click a button to open the lightbox it will show information fine, until you've opened/closed the lightbox about 6 times.

I'm running v9.0.0 of Node, and I've got maxSockets to Infinity.

**My route:**

```
app.get('/active-item', function(req, res) {
    if (typeof req.headers.referer !== 'undefined') {
        if (req.session.user!==undefined) {
            res.render('pages/active-item', { user: req.session.user, email_address: req.session.user.emailAddress });
        } else {
            res.render('pages/active-item');
        }
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

On the 6th attempt it just doesn't load the data in the lightbox and then after about 10-20 seconds, I see the requests come through my logs on Express. Very strange issue, I thought it was a maxSockets issue but it doesn't seem so.

I've seen similar issues online but all seems to be solved by setting maxSockets to Infinity. Am I leaving a connection open on my route? I can't possibly think what else I haven't covered.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like your app is doing some DB stuff with each request, but you’re  only showing code for a route that renders pages? Where’s the code that runs when you click images, which is what you say is slowing things down?